# Input: 123 -123 Output: 0 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:

Tags: java

```
  public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String num = sc.next();
        String[] partsOfNums = num.split("\\-");
        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(partsOfNums[0]);
        int num2 = Integer.parseInt(partsOfNums[1]);
        int result = num1 - num2;
        System.out.println(result);

    }

}
```

I want to input 123 -123 and print out 0 but I'm getting the error.

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at codingexercises.Main.main(Main.java:12)
```

What's wrong with the code?

Comment: You have space between 123(space)-123 and so it is giving you above exception. Your input should be 123-123.

Comment: Try this: `String[] partsOfNums = num.split("-");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Read the whole line instead of next string token
- Need not add escape character while split

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String num = sc.nextLine();
        String[] partsOfNums = num.split("-");
        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(partsOfNums[0].trim());
        int num2 = Integer.parseInt(partsOfNums[1].trim());
        int result = num1 - num2;
        System.out.println(result);

    }
}
```